# Feature extraction for images of text

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection

What is a good [feature extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction#Image_processing) algorithm for images consisting largely of text (possibly rotated and scaled)?

An example use-case would be that I scan a document, extract features from it, and then match the features to those of frames from a video of a desk to find the time when the document was sitting on the desk.

To be more precise, I am aware that there exist numerous feature extraction algorithms, but I'm wondering if there are any such algorithms that can take advantage of prevalence of text in an image (high contrast, many corners, etc), and then find an occurrence of that image (possibly affine-transformed in some way) in a larger, non-text-only image.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely refer to the [Locally Likely Arrangement Hashing](http://www.m.cs.osakafu-u.ac.jp/~nakai/pdf/das.pdf) method (a.k.a geometrical features) which is precisely used for camera-based document image retrieval.